# How do I profile my app - the menu item is disabled?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How do I profile my app in xcode - the menu item is disabled?

Product > Profile is disabled

Comment: Which menu items are disabled?

Comment: The profile menu item is disabled

Comment: Check whether your scheme is validated or not?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

This is very unlikely but still, one possible reason:

Make sure correct 'Executable' is selected in 'Profile' option for your Scheme. If the selected executable is 'None', profile option will be disabled.

In case you don't know how to check scheme settings, you can check these setting by selecting 'Edit Scheme' either from Scheme menu (App name and device/simulator drop downs near the Run and Stop button ) or from 'Product' menu of xcode

Comment: Wow, my profile menu has been disabled for over a month, and I just thought it was the beta that did it so didn't investigate further.  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Ha! Have had this with a project for a long time. Thanks for suggesting this obvious solution

Comment: No idea how that happened, but this answered saved me all sort of problems. Thanks!

Comment: I think this happened to me when I added a Share extension to my project. In Xcode 6.3 there was a bunch of things I needed to fix in the project/plist. I wouldn't be surprised if it changed my scheme too.

Comment: I have to executables in the workspace, so I guess that's why None is selected by default.

Comment: Thanks for this - this was my exact problem. I have this happen once a year or so - I find the same answer, attempt to upvote it, and realize I've already done so in the past :-)

Answer (score 0):

My profile menu item was also dimmed.

I realized I had disconnected my iPhone from my Mac which broke the product destination link. If you've been testing on your phone, try resetting the product destination.

If the phone doesn't show up in the Product/Destination submenu do the following:

1. Run a terminal session.
2. In terminal type the following:

```
sudo launchctl stop com.apple.usbmuxd
```

3. Unplug and replug your phone to your Mac.
4. If your phone still doesn't appear in the Product/Destination submenu,  restart Xcode and repeat step three.
5. Set your phone in the Product/Destination submenu.
6. Your Profile menu item should be undimmed.